# Java. Get RGB histogram

Tags: java, jfreechart, histogram

Is my code right?
i want to get RGB histogram using JAI and Jfreechart.

1)create Histogram object from planarimage
2)histogram.getBins() to get RGB value
3)plot this values on barchart from jfreechart

Hope u will help me! 
Thx :)

```
PlanarImage.wrapRenderedImage(img);
           ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();

    int[] bins = { 256 };
    double[] low = { 0.0D };
    double[] high = { 256.0D };

    pb.addSource(img);
    pb.add(null);
    pb.add(1);
    pb.add(1);
    pb.add(bins);
    pb.add(low);
    pb.add(high);

    RenderedOp op = JAI.create("histogram", pb, null);
    Histogram histogram = (Histogram) op.getProperty("histogram");

    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    int[][] data = histogram.getBins();
    for (int i = 1; i<data.length;i++){
        dataset.setValue(data[0][i], "color", String.valueOf(data[1][i]) );
    }
   JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("test", 
   "test", "test", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, 
   false, true, false);
   try {
   ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File("C:\\chart.jpg"), chart, 500, 300);
   } catch (IOException e) {
   System.err.println("Problem occurred creating chart.");
   }
```

Comment: what is your question? P.S is my code alright is not a question on SO

Comment: sry :)
is my logic right?
problem - my result(image) dont load on my harddisk

Comment: What do you mean "don't load on my harddisk"? Is the file missing? Is there an error opening it?